# summing vectors in Python

Tags: python, vector, sum

Hi I am trying to add the 3rd column in the following example of input:

input1:

```
act hi  1
act bye 2
act ciao    5
```

input2:

```
art hi  1
art bye 2
art kiss    5
```

with the following desired output:

```
act-art hi  2
act-art bye 4
act-art kiss    5
act-art ciao    5
```

Below is the code that I have been working with.

```
def sumVectors(classB_infile, classA_infile, outfile):

    class_dictA = {}

    with open(classA_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_A:
        for line in opened_infile_A:
            items = line.split()
            classA, feat, valuesA = items[:3]
            class_dictA[feat] = float(valuesA)


    class_dictB = {}

    with open(classB_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_B:
        for line in opened_infile_B:
            items = line.split()
            classB, feat, valuesB = items[:3]
            class_dictB[feat] = float(valuesB)


#print classA, classB, feat, sumVectors

####outfile 
    with open(outfile, "wb") as output_file:
        for key in class_dictA:
            if key in class_dictB:
                weight = class_dictA[key] + class_dictB[key]
                #outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" +  classB, key, str(weight)])
            else:
                weight = class_dictA[key]
                outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" +  classB, key, str(weight)])
                output_file.write(outstring + "\n")

        for key in class_dictB:
            if key in class_dictA:
                weight = class_dictB[key]
            outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" + classB, key, str(weight)])
            output_file.write(outstring + "\n")
```

However, it gives me the following output:

```
act-art stress  5.0
act-art bye 2.0
act-art hi  1.0
act-art kiss    1.0
```

Any insight as to why it is not summing the values in common in the 2nd column?
Thank you

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? It's a bit hard to tell what your code is doing.

Comment: Are you doing this as a learning exercise or in production? If the latter things would be much simpler [using a database](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) or something like the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library.

Comment: Its a simplified example of a production case I am working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This contains the simplest fixes to achieve the desired result:

```
def sumVectors(classB_infile, classA_infile, outfile):
    class_dictA = {}

    with open(classA_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_A:
        for line in opened_infile_A:
            items = line.split()
            classA, feat, valuesA = items[:3]
            class_dictA[feat.strip()] = float(valuesA)


    class_dictB = {}

    with open(classB_infile, "rb") as opened_infile_B:
        for line in opened_infile_B:
            items = line.split()
            classB, feat, valuesB = items[:3]
            class_dictB[feat.strip()] = float(valuesB)

    ####outfile 
    with open(outfile, "wb") as output_file:
        for key in class_dictA:
            if key in class_dictB:
                weight = class_dictA[key] + class_dictB[key]
                outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" +  classB, key, str(weight)])
            else:
                weight = class_dictA[key]
                outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" +  classB, key, str(weight)])
            output_file.write(outstring + "\n")

        for key in class_dictB:
            if key not in class_dictA: # if key was in A it was processed already
                weight = class_dictB[key]
                outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" + classB, key, str(weight)])
                output_file.write(outstring + "\n")
```

However this can really be simplified:

```
def readFile(fileName, keys):
    result = {}
    class_ = ''
    with open(fileName, "rb") as opened_infile_A:
        for line in opened_infile_A:
            items = line.split()
            class_, feat, value = items[:3]
            keys.add(feat)
            result[feat] = float(value)
    return (class_, result)


def sumVectors(classB_infile, classA_infile, outfile):
    keys = set()

    classA, class_dictA = readFile(classA_infile, keys)
    classB, class_dictB = readFile(classB_infile, keys)

    with open(outfile, "wb") as output_file:
        for key in keys:
            weightA = class_dictA[key] if key in class_dictA else 0
            weightB = class_dictB[key] if key in class_dictB else 0
            weight = weightA + weightB
            outstring = "\t".join([classA + "-" +  classB, key, str(weight)])
            output_file.write(outstring + "\n")
```

Comment: I think that instead of two loops at the end over `for key in class_dictA:` and `for key in class_dictB:` it should iterate over the set union of the keys.

Comment: @MrE Yes, exactly. I've just updated with an example refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing a two loops to implement the "merging" of the two dictionaries, I recommend to use a defaultdict:

```
result = collections.defaultdict(float, class_dictA)
for k, v in class_dictB.items(): result[k] += v
```

What this does is to create a new `result` dictionary which is a copy of `class_dictA`. Then, you add all the values in `class_dictB` to the `result` dictionary. If a key doesn't exist yet, it's treated the same as if it had the value (which is what calling `float()` does).